# GetDateFormat returning invalid short date for ky-KG (Kyrgyz - Kyrgyzstan)

Tags: windows, date, localization, internationalization

Windows reports that the "short date" format (`LOCALE_SShortDate`) for ky-KG is:

```
d-MMM yy
```

The date format string contains [picture codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/day--month--year--and-era-format-pictures). Other pictures codes are `d`, `dd`, `ddd`, `dddd`, `M`, `MM`, `MMM`, `MMMM`, `yy`, `yyyy`.

For english people, the resulting string that uses that date format would be:

```
16-Oct 21
\/ \_/ \/
d  MMM yy
```

Because `MMM` is taken to mean the *"Abbreviated month as specified by a LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME* value, for example, "Oct" in English (United States)."*

And for English locales, those "abbreviated month names" would be:

| Locale Info | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME1` | Jan |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME2` | Feb |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME3` | Mar |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME4` | Apr |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME5` | May |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME6` | Jun |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME7` | Jul |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME8` | Aug |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME9` | Sep |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME10` | Oct |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME11` | Nov |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME12` | Dec |

You can use the [**GetDateFormat** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformatw) to return you a date that follows the abbreviated month names for English.

So to format a date with the format string of `d-MMM yy`, using the `en-US` locale you would call something like: *(pseudocode)*

```
GetDateFormat(1033, LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE, &systemTime, "d-MMM yy", buffer, bufferLen);
```

Returning a formatted string of the form:

- <kbd>16-Oct 21</kbd>
  `d.MMM yy`

### Now for Kyrgyzstan

Kyrgyz uses different abbreviations for its months; which makes sense since they don't speak English:

| Locale Info | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME1` | янв |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME2` | фев |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME3` | мар |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME4` | апр |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME5` | май |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME6` | июн |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME7` | июл |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME8` | авг |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME9` | сен |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME10` | окт |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME11` | ноя |
| `LOCALE_SABBREVMONTHNAME12` | дек |

When i try the same call to [**GetDateFormat**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformatw) for the `ky-KG` locale:

```
GetDateFormat(1088, LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE, &systemTime, "d-MMM yy", buffer, bufferLen);
```

I get a resulting formatted date string of:

- <kbd>16-окт. 21</kbd>
           ^

Notice the extra `.` in there.

That doesn't match the short date format string:

- **Expected**: `d-MMM yy`
- **Actual**: `d-MMM. yy`

### It's a bug, but how to work around it?

If Windows is telling me:

- that the *"short date format"* is `d-MMM yy`
- and that the abbreviated name of `Октябрь` is `окт`
- and Windows provides the function to format a date using those strings

Why is Windows generating a string that Windows says the string should look like?

It's a pain when you try to parse a date generated by Windows, and that date generated by Windows does not match the format the Windows says the format should be.

What is going on, and how do i fix it in a locale neutral-way?

Windows 10.0.19043.1237

### Bonus Chatter

Kyrgyzstan is the only locale that doesn't use `MM` (*i.e.* numbers) in their short date.

Bulgaria and Turkmenistan have a short date format that includes fixed suffixes:

- Bulgaria: `d.M.yyyy 'г.'`
- Turkmenistan: `dd.MM.yy 'ý.'`

Neat! I don't know what the suffix abbreviations stand for; but it's just neat to see.

### Bonus Reading

- [glibc locale helper for Kirghiz](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/ky_KG/)